# Rerun code while debugging and while reloading all modules

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, ipdb

When debugging my Python code, I run a script through ipdb from the command line, and set a number of breakpoints.  Then I make some changes in one or more modules, and rerun.  However, if I simply use `run` modules do not get reloaded.  To make sure they do, I can exit and restart Python completely, but then I need to [reset all breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28841520/974555), which is tedious if I have many and if done over and over again.

Is there a way to restart a run in (i)pdb, and make sure all modules get recursively reloaded?

Comment: a similar question has already been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506971/recursive-version-of-reload

Comment: @EliKorvigo Not really.  I would still need a way to run this inside `ipdb`, and take effect in the surrounding code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make pdb recognize that the source has changed between runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724924/how-to-make-pdb-recognize-that-the-source-has-changed-between-runs)