# Save breakpoints to file

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, ipdb

When debugging my Python code, I run a script through ipdb from the commandline, and set a number of breakpoints. Then I make some changes in one or more modules, and rerun. However, if I simply use run modules [do not get reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28841411/974555).  To make sure they do, I can exist and restart Python completely, but then I need to reset all breakpoints, which is tedious if I have many and if done over and over again.

Is there a way to save breakpoint to a file in (i)pdb, so that after small changes that do not change line numbers, I can dump my breakpoints, restart Python + pdb, and reload my breakpoints?  The equivalent to Matlabs `X = dbstatus`, saving/loading `X`, and setting `dbstop(X)`.

Answer (score 10):

You can save the breakpoints to `.pdbrc` file in a working path or globally to your home dir. File should have something like this:

```
# breakpoint 1
break /path/to/file:lineno

# breakpoint 2
break /path/to/file:lineno
```

You can define breakpoints various ways, just like in the interactive mode. So just `break 4` or `break method` will work too.

This file works for both, pdb and ipdb, since later has everything pdb has and more.

**Bonus**:

You could use `alias` to more easily save breakpoints.
For example:

```
# append breakpoint to .pdbrc in current working directory
# usage: bs lineno
alias bs with open(".pdbrc", "a") as pdbrc: pdbrc.write("break " + __file__ + ":%1\n")
```

Put above to your global .pdbrc and use it like this:

```
> bs 15
```

This will append a breakpoint statement to a local .pdbrc file for a line 15 of current file.

It is not perfect solution, but close enough for me. Tune the command to your needs.

[Read more about aliases here.](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-alias)

Comment: Is there a direct way of writing/appending the current set of breakpoints, apart from typing `break` and copy-pasting the results to `.pdbrc`?

Comment: @gerrit no, but you could take advantage of aliases. Updated the answer.